# Canadian enterprise level hosting

Tags: hosting

A client is looking to move some of their servers from a Canadian west coast DC, to another provider due to some poor vendor response times.

The requirements are:

- Canadian Based
- Hardware is fully managed.
- Hardware load balancer
- Modest backups (500Gb)
- Dual Quad Xeon
- 32Gb RAM

Those sorts of hardware requirements aren't off the shelf, so I realize that there would be some lead times involved. I'm having a hard time coming up with other Canadian providers.

If some folks that that have had good experiences with Canadian DC providers could reply, it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Q9 Networks: http://q9.com/

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

In Vancouver, you can try In2net: http://www.in2net.com/

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [iWeb](http://iweb.com/) for a good five years and I only have good things to say about them.

Their response time is in the matter of minutes and their prices are competitive. They are located in Montreal (which for me is literally next door).

Answer (score 1):

I know iWeb is pretty big in Canada, unless they're the ones that are having poor response times.

I'd also recommend keeping backups off-site, in case of any disaster, so go with a company like RoyalBackup.com, which started up recently.

Answer (score 1):

Could try http://www.stardothosting.com/, they're located in Toronto and do managed service.

Answer (score 1):

RackForce

http://www.rackforce.com/

They have a data center in Kelowna, BC with decent bandwidth and low latency. I used them for 1 month about a year back to host a website that was temporarily popular. I can't vouch for their support because I wasn't there long enough for anything to go wrong, but my experience was exclusively positive.